# Можно ли группировать контроллеры в папке controller?

Tags: .net, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Например, у меня большое приложение=> у меня может быть дофига контроллеров.

Если они будут валяться в корневой папке, то тяжело будет найти нужный.

Есть ли возможность сгруппировать все это по подпапкам? Слышал про areas.

Их можно использовать для этого?

Как я понимаю, в этом случае я смогу добавить только 1 уровень подпапок?

Comment: Ох как давно на .net не работал. Но вроде в своё время мне помогли эти две страницы: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310833/why-does-everyone-put-controllers-in-one-folder-and-views-in-another  и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703430/asp-net-mvc-controller-subfolder  Может и вам поможет.

Comment: Да, можно. Создавай папки в Студии и раскидай контроллеры по ним. Это же чисто логическое группирование. Никакие пути менять не придется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а если ещё неймспейсы поменять, то все поломается?